# Chrome Extension: Handling Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, events, onclick

I want to write a little chrome-extension, which does something on clicking on specific buttons on a specific page. The Problem is: How can I implement a click-event in a chrome-extension? I've always used jQuerys selector + on('click', 'element', callbackfunction); ...

Anyone knows how?

Kindly Regards

Comment: What will it be doing? Is jQuery really necessary?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I want to "parse" the content of a textbox when a send-button is clicked (A specific button from a specific textarea from a specific website), so that for example "xyz" will be changed to "zyx" externaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with the hassle of jQuery and just use something like:

```
document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    var _this = e.target; //the submit button
    var text = document.getElementById('theForm').getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
    return text!="";
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks! I never knew that .addEventListener existed o.o

Answer (score 1):

You can still use jquery with a chrome extension, but you need to put if out of the `html`

my_script.js and your version of `jquery` to the `html`

and then, in my_script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your jquery here
});
```

I'm not sure that the $(document).ready... is required, it depend if you put the script balises in the head or at the end of you body

I hope it will helps you

Comment: Thanks! Though, I didn't want to use jQuery :/ Nearly solved anyway :)

Comment: If you don't want to use jquery, just put you javascript code in `my_script.js` file. Google policy forbid you to put script in the `html` for an extension, but you can add some if you put it in files.