# How can a Chrome extension respond to a button click in a page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a first attempt at writing a Chrome extension and I want it to respond to a button click which resembles the facebook like button, G+ button, etc.  This means that I'd like the extension to work on any page, but only respond to a button with a particular ID or something, which seems tricky with the "permission" and/or "matches" item of the JSON manifest.

Since I'm unfamiliar with extensions, should I have the button have its own javascript function which calls/activates the extension somehow, or should I have the extension have an event listener (would this be in a content script?) which listens for a particular button click event?

Note: I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723848/chrome-extension-handling-clicks)
but the extension in that case was for a specific web page, so I'm not convinced that the answer will work for me.

Comment: use a content script; there's nothing much harder about implementing such a button from a content script than from each webpage yourself. if that answers your question. you could also implement that "button" as an iframe to an extension page (like chrome-extension://yourextensionid/button.html). whatever works for you, depends on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you want is that your extension should work on all pages, so include your content script in manifest as follows :

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": [
            "jquery.js",
            "myscript.js"
        ]
    }
```

This will inject myscript.js in every page. Now just check if your desired button is present or not. eg :

```
if(document.getElementById('gplus') != null) {
   // Add your implementation.
   var g = document.getElementById('gplus');
   g.click = funct;
}
```

Now define function funct() according to yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that "<all_urls"> was an option.  Now I can find a button!

Answer (score 0):

try using content scripts.
They act like they are part of the page.  if i had a `document.getelementbyid("#hi").onclick=function(){};` and someone clicked a button with an id of "hi" inside the current page, the event would fire.

Read more at:https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts